# Can Docker environment variables be used as an dynamic entrypoint runtime arg?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to parameterize my Dockerfile running nodeJS so I can have my entrypoint command's args be customizable on `docker run` so I can maintain one container artifact that can be deployed repeatedly with variations to some runtime args.

I've tried a few different ways, the most basic being

```
ENV CONFIG_FILE=default.config.js

ENTRYPOINT node ... --config ${CONFIG_FILE}
```

What I'm finding is that whatever value is defaulted remains in my `docker run` command even if I'm using `-e` to pass in new values.  Such as

```
docker run -e CONFIG_FILE=desired.config.js
```

Another Dockerfile form I've tried is this:

```
ENTRYPOINT node ... --config ${CONFIG_FILE:-default.config.js}
```

Not specifying the environment variable with an `ENV` directive, but using bash expansion to specify a default value if nonexistent or null is found.  This gives me the same behavior though.

Lastly, the last thing I tried was to create a bash script file that contains the same entrypoint command, then `ADD` it to the docker context and invoke it in my `ENTRYPOINT`.  And this also seems to give the same behavior.

Is what I'm attempting even possible?

EDIT:

Here is a minimal dockerfile that reproduces this behavior for me:

```
FROM alpine

ENV CONFIG "no"

ENTRYPOINT  echo "CONFIG=${CONFIG}"
```

Here is the build command:

```
docker build -f test.Dockerfile -t test .
```

Here is the run command, which echoes `no` despite the `-e` arg:

```
docker run -t test -e CONFIG=yes
```

Some additional details, 
I'm running `OSX sierra` with a Docker version of `18.09.2, build 6247962`

Comment: Can you give a complete example of a failing case?  All of the variants you show _should_ work the way you expect (with the `docker run -e` option overriding the Dockerfile `ENV`, and being substituted into the shell-form command).

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes, the new content below the EDIT is a minimum verifiable example that reproduces the issue for me.

Comment: `-e CONFIG` needs to come before the image name; but if I do that, I can run your sample and get the expected result.

Comment: @DavidMaze That's it.  The problem wasn't in my dockerfile, but my `docker run` command having it's arguments out of order